# Как проверять язык через /ru/ в ссылке?

Tags: php

Вот сайт есть

```
    Русская
       site/ru/product/...
    Укр
       site/product/...
```

Как проверять что это ru?

```
if(...){
  echo "RU";
}else{
 echo "Uk";
}
```

Comment: РусСкая с двумя 'с' пишеться

Comment: @NewView а «пишеться» без мягкого знака ;]

Answer (score 0):

Можно регулярным выражением:

```
if(preg_match('~/ru/~i', $url)) { // very good }
```

Comment: Не роботает????

Comment: У вас в регекспе слэши в правильную сторону?